# JDBC - Retrieve entire data as a List

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I'm trying to build a class that retrieves each row from a MySQL table and store it to a List but my code doesn't compile and throws me an error

> Error: Main method not found in class
>   MySQLAccountsDatabankReader,
>   please define the main method as:    public static void main(String[]
>   args)

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class MySQLAccountsDatabankReader {

    private static List<String[]> accounts;

    public MySQLAccountsDatabankReader(String[] args) {

        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "mysql";

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test.accounts;");

            if (rs.next()) {
                ArrayList<String[]> accounts = new ArrayList<String[]>();
                rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test.accounts;");
                int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String[] row = new String[columnCount];
                    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                        row[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);
                    }
                    accounts.add(row);

                            }
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(MySQLAccountsDatabankReader.class
                    .getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(MySQLAccountsDatabankReader.class
                        .getName());
                lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        }
        return accounts;

    }
}
```

Revision 0.2 - I've got the following compilation error - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    accounts cannot be resolved
    accounts cannot be resolved to a variable

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MySQLAccountsDatabankReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MySQLAccountsDatabankReader reader = new MySQLAccountsDatabankReader();

        List<String[]> accounts = reader.getAccounts();

    }

    public List<String[]> getAccounts() {

        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "mysql";

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test.accounts;");

            if (rs.next()) {

                rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test.accounts;");
                int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String[] row = new String[columnCount];
                    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                        row[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);
                    }
                    accounts.add(row);

                }
                return accounts;

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(MySQLAccountsDatabankReader.class
                    .getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(MySQLAccountsDatabankReader.class
                        .getName());
                lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiler errors are usually a good indicator of what is wrong - you need a `main` method.

Also, non-declarative statements need to be in a method, constructor or static initializer rather than in the class code block. Place your `JDBC` code within a method. Here you need a method that will return `accounts` to match your `return` statement. Also you need to create an instance of `List`, e.g. `ArrayList` to return.

```
private List<String[]> getAccounts() {
   List<String[]> accounts = new ArrayList<String[]>();
   ...

   return accounts;
}
```

and add a `main` method entry point:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   MySQLAccountsDatabankReader reader = new MySQLAccountsDatabankReader();
   List<String[]> accounts = reader.getAccounts();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift response but after I re-factored it like this I've got
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 accounts cannot be resolved
 accounts cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Create a new `ArrayList` at the beginning or your method and have the return statement as the last to ensure there is something to return. See update.

Answer (score 0):

Add main method:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
  new MySQLAccountsDatabankReader(args);
}
```